# Custom Heroku name only masking the root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cname

I just bought a Domain name from IWantMyDomain.com and am using it as a custom domain on Heroku to mask my app name. The name works fine for the root page with both  http://www.snapclasp.com and the naked version, but all the other pages on the app revert back to the Heroku app name http://instapin.herokuapp.com when they progress through the site.

There is lots of info about masking subdomains but I can't find anything on just masking all of my routes/urls. Is this an error or something wrong with my setup?

I have 2 CNAME records with hostnames of "www" and "*" pointing to instapin.herokuapp.com. Do I need to use something like DNSsimple to host my dns?

Comment: This seems to work? http://snapclasp.com/terms

Comment: Did you follow Heroku's instructions on setting up custom domain names? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to Heroku via the [CLI toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and explicitly add your domain as a [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#custom-subdomains):

```
# from command line
heroku domains:add snapclasp.com
heroku domains:add www.snapclasp.com
```

Comment: The masking was working for the other pages. There was an internal redirect bring the herokuapp.com domain back to the browser. Didn't notice it until you said it was working for the static page you looked at.

Answer (score 1):

In the web interface, under settings for the app, you need to add the domains you want to use. It's located under the setting for your GitHub repository name.

[This page has more detailed information about setting up custom domains.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)